# How to find the line?

Tags: r, clustering

Today I faced what I think is a very simple problem, but could't solve. I have this plot (data is below)

`with(mydata, plot(x, y))`

[image]

It's clear that there are two groups here, right? I would like to find a line that discriminates these two groups, like this one (found manually).

`plot(mydata$x, mydata$y); abline(9, .36)`

[image]

Questions

What technique should I use? Could anyone provide R code to solve it, please?

`mydata <- structure(list(y = c(24.91543, 20.93154, 33.38601, 32.6498, 38.96774, 
20.51704, 10.64043, 35.69466, 28.72396, 31.80371, 34.11269, 31.64434, 
25.5895, 33.58181, 34.34093, 25.92858, 32.21135, 30.19319, 30.27322, 
24.43336, 26.00838, 35.42962, 26.46969, 32.88677, 21.21332, 25.6222, 
36.60242, 27.00271, 40.59243, 29.02613, 30.10023, 15.59976, 41.07338, 
31.13055, 34.00474, 37.13078, 30.70407, 30.80497, 32.9493, 42.1743, 
38.7733, 26.01051, 32.47489, 21.95968, 25.1595, 38.58872, 27.98961, 
42.83003, 31.08639, 34.62195, 38.96774, 32.56765, 16.40093, 35.18166, 
39.06299, 34.79893, 22.88687, 35.44114, 37.627, 34.91972, 25.11421, 
26.3312, 42.68491, 34.94547, 16.22444, 29.20567, 21.39507, 27.31063, 
38.83989, 18.57524, 28.76647, 39.07916, 36.94783, 25.35636, 38.4268, 
42.10769, 44.762, 21.71412, 36.63178, 25.50169, 37.27536, 28.62975, 
25.89833, 26.34055, 20.88283, 29.91666, 40.16116, 38.72035, 30.23885, 
29.58979, 19.41681, 23.4266, 31.84684, 32.46026, 34.90148, 23.12917, 
30.60789, 15.79587, 33.64789, 30.11133), x = c(37.139999, 50, 
60, 90, 96.669998, 46.669998, 20, 62.860001, 37.139999, 54.290001, 
93.330002, 48.57, 70, 90, 60, 73.330002, 54.290001, 45.709999, 
40, 28.57, 70, 60, 34.290001, 51.43, 50, 37.139999, 68.57, 37.139999, 
80, 34.290001, 37.139999, 30, 80, 83.330002, 54.290001, 65.709999, 
42.860001, 83.330002, 48.57, 85.709999, 74.290001, 70, 54.290001, 
22.860001, 31.43, 68.57, 76.669998, 82.860001, 42.860001, 57.139999, 
96.669998, 51.43, 26.67, 60, 96.669998, 60, 28.57, 62.860001, 
65.709999, 62.860001, 28.57, 70, 85.709999, 62.860001, 30, 80, 
28.57, 73.330002, 71.43, 50, 48.57, 77.139999, 93.330002, 70, 
68.57, 85.709999, 100, 22.860001, 93.330002, 70, 68.57, 80, 66.669998, 
70, 14.29, 42.860001, 96.669998, 96.669998, 83.330002, 51.43, 
14.29, 60, 45.709999, 51.43, 57.139999, 28.57, 45.709999, 23.33, 
54.290001, 83.330002)), .Names = c("y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: What do you mean "find the line?" Do you have the intercept and slope?
What you are probably looking for is discriminant analysis. http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/discriminant.html

Comment: I would like to find the intercept and the slope. I can't use discriminant analysis because I don't have the groups yet, am I right?

Comment: Maybe what I want is an unsupervised algorithm that separates space in two groups, like kmeans. However, kmeans does not provide a function, just centroids. I've already ran it but got no luck (it separated my plot in left and right)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a "better" solution, but you'll get what you want from a mixture of clustering and ANCOVA.

First, create a 2 group cluster (using, for instance, Kmeans). Then use the cluster assignments as a categorical predictor in an ANCOVA. The intercept and the slope for your continuous variable are the values you are looking for (assuming you use sum-to-zero codes on your categorical predictor).

```
set.seed(1234)

x1<-rnorm(50,0,.1)
shift<-c(rep(0,25),rep(3,25))
y<-2+3*x1+shift+rnorm(50,0,.3)

fit<-kmeans(cbind(scale(x1),scale(y)),2)

x2<-factor(fit$cluster)

contrasts(x2)<-contr.helmert(2)

plot(x1,y,col=fit$cluster)

sum.1<-summary(lm(y~x1+x2))

abline(sum.1$coefficients[1],sum.1$coefficients[2])
sum.1
```

Admittedly, kmeans clustering may not always give you exactly the results you are looking for. A nearest neighbor hierarchical clustering may be better.

Comment: This assumes the slopes of the two lines are the same, possibly an interaction between `x1` and `x2` would be better?

Comment: Very nice. I think that the "same slope" assumption works great for my data. It is clear now that I need some usupervised + some regression to solve this kind of problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is where the question starts to get too vague, Matthew. Technically there are infinite lines that separate them, assuming the sets are convex. I think the general case can be solved using separating hyperplanes and support vectors, but its been WAY too long since I've done that kind of math. Even with different slopes, though, the ANCOVA results should find A line that separates them, though maybe its not the "best" however you define that.

Comment: E.g. if you do the same procedure with the following y values (with different slopes for the different groups) you'll still get a separating line, even though it looks odd.
`y2<-2+3*x1*shift+shift+rnorm(50,0,.3)`

Comment: As Vincent demonstrates in his answer below (and you mention in your answer), simple `kmeans` would perform quite poorly here (due to isotropic covariance). Mixture of Gaussians should work well. I don't think hierarchical clustering, just based on Euclidian distances, would work either.

Answer (score 8):

In order to find this line, you have first to find the two groups. There is a super cool R library called [`FlexMix`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/flexmix-intro.pdf) that allows you to find the two clusters. The method used here aims at finding 2 (`k=2`) different linear models (`y~x`) in the data. The methods is based on an iterative process that can yield slightly different results between 2 different runs, that's why I used `set.seed(123)`.

```
set.seed(123)
require(flexmix)
res.flex <- flexmix(y~x, data=mydata, k=2)  
plot(y~x, data=mydata, col=res.flex@cluster)
```

[image: Flexmix Result]

Once you have the groups, you can apply your favorite classification algorithm, like discriminant analysis:

```
require(MASS)
Z <- scale(mydata)
g <- factor(res.flex@cluster)
res.lda <- lda(g~., data=data.frame(g=g, Z))

gmean <- res.lda$prior%*%res.lda$means
const <- drop(gmean%*%res.lda$scaling)

slope <- -res.lda$scaling[1]/res.lda$scaling[2]
intercept <- const/res.lda$scaling[2]
```

The resulting linear separator is in green in the following plot.

```
plot(y~x, data=Z, col=g)
abline(intercept, slope, col=3)
```

[image: Linear Separator]

Just for fun, I tried to find the two groups with K-Means, and the resulting groups was not great at all :

[image: Kmeans]

---

EDIT 1: Following @le_andrew's comment below, here are the resulting clusters after scaling:

```
Z <- scale(mydata)
plot(y~x, data=Z, col=kmeans(Z,2)$cluster)
```

[image: After Scaling]

---

EDIT 2: I found in [these examples](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~johnm/r-book/2edn/exercises/scripts/chap12.R) how to compute the slope and intercept of the linear separator, I directly edited my previous code.

---

EDIT 3: Since `flexmix` uses posterior probabilities to identify the clusters, maybe we could use its output to directly deduce the linear separator. I don't know yet how to do that, though.

Comment: Since the scales of your data are different, you should be standardizing before doing kmeans.

Comment: Without more guidance to the algorithm, who's to say that the FlexMix grouping is "better" than the K-Means (with or without scaling)? Different, yes, but better? Better because that is the grouping the OP wants? If the OP already knows what he wants, he could just draw the line himeself, as he did.

Comment: This is a very good remark. [FlexMix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/flexmix-intro.pdf) was developed to identify a mixture of models. I used it here because there seems to be a mixture of two linear models in the scatterplot and because none of the methods I tried before using it could recover the two groups the OP wanted to automatically get. If you look closely at the OP's Figure and the result of FlexMix, you will see that the two clusters are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the linear model and get the intercept and slope from the summary, as the coefficients give you the slope.

```
lm(y ~ x)
```

This should give you the coefficients (i.e. the slope).

Comment: It's just a regression line, it does not separate my plot in the "right" two groups.